# SQL Joins with distinct columns

Tags: sql, db2

Consider two (possibly temporary) tables X and Y each with many columns. In DB2, if I make a cross join like this,

```
select *
from X, Y
where X.key=Y.key
```

I get the error SQLCODE=-153, SQLSTATE=42908, which complains about duplicate column names (surely, "key" occurs twice). The [help page](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/dzichelp/v2r2/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db2z9.doc.codes/src/tpc/n153.htm) here suggests to specify the column names exactly, but this is cumbersome due to the large number of columns.

Is there a way to retain the compact syntax and get the full data? Or asked differently, is it possible to use only distinct rows, i.e. let "key" appear only once?

Comment: do you need to join the tables? `select X.*, Y.* from X join Y on X.key=Y.key;`

Comment: This is not a cross join, as far as I can see.

Comment: Yes, it is a cross join.

Comment: What are you trying to do here? The [description](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPEK_10.0.0/com.ibm.db2z10.doc.codes/src/tpc/n153.dita) for `-151` indicates that this is will happen when you're trying to create a view or a temporary table.

Comment: Also, no... it's *not* a [`CROSS JOIN`](https://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/dzichelp/v2r2/topic/com.ibm.db2z10.doc.sqlref/src/tpc/db2z_sql_joinoperations.htm). A real cross-join creates a [Cartesian product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product) of `X` with `Y`. What you're doing is the "old" `SQL-89` style inner join.

Answer (score 0):

Not that i know of. You could make this:

```
select X.*, Y.Field1, Y.Field2, ...from X, Y where X.key=Y.key
```

So you get all the fields from X, but you need to explicit name the field on Y.

Comment: Ok, thanks, but this is not what I meant by "compact syntax" -- in fact, that is exactly the solution I wanted to avoid because then I would have to specify, say, 8 million columns ... ;-)

Comment: Sorry, but what you want (as long as i know) is not posible. You can only have all the fields (without explicit name them) of one table. For second table you need to name the fields explicit if columns names repeat. Other option will be to make some query over catalog databases and find columns name from them. Then dinamic build you query. Sorry.

Comment: Thanks, getting the names of the fields is not the problem, but then the queries become much larger. I'm really asking myself why that isn't possible ... I mean, in any cross join you have redundant infomation ...

Comment: I wouldn't advice to use SELECT * at all. It's not a good practice and can lead to a lot of trouble. In general when you create a query you now wich data you need. Using SELECT * means that you don´t know wich fields are you getting nor its order. Besides can consume network traffic that you need for something else. The idea is when you query a database request ONLY the data that you realy need.

Comment: I agree in principle. My setting is database testing: many temporary tables (one for each transformation step), few data sets, hence no need not to include each column. For this setting, I wanted to avoid specifiying column names for each temporary table. But ok, it doesn't seem to work. Thanks